# count number of instances in data frame

Tags: r

For each unique string in `X1` i would like get the number of instances where `value` is positive and negative.

data:

```
> head(tab_split_merge.m)
                                    IsomiR    logCPM       LR       PValue          FDR              X1                        X2 variable     value
1 hsa-miR-135b-5p_TATGGCTTTTCATTCCTATGTGAA 3.7839592 96.44248 9.187474e-23 2.002777e-18 hsa-miR-135b-5p  TATGGCTTTTCATTCCTATGTGAA    logFC  4.741782
2  hsa-miR-135b-5p_TATGGCTTTTCATTCCTATGTGA 5.6750976 93.55073 3.959207e-22 4.315338e-18 hsa-miR-135b-5p   TATGGCTTTTCATTCCTATGTGA    logFC  4.105579
3   hsa-miR-135b-5p_TATGGCTTTTCATTCCTATGTG 4.7075541 91.62360 1.048355e-21 7.617695e-18 hsa-miR-135b-5p    TATGGCTTTTCATTCCTATGTG    logFC  4.120676
4  hsa-miR-21-5p_GTAGCTTATCAGACTGATGTTGACC 0.5600979 79.52288 4.766726e-19 2.597746e-15   hsa-miR-21-5p GTAGCTTATCAGACTGATGTTGACC    logFC  3.811973
5   hsa-miR-135b-3p_ATGTAGGGCTAAAAGCCATGGG 0.9542581 75.22223 4.206038e-18 1.833749e-14 hsa-miR-135b-3p    ATGTAGGGCTAAAAGCCATGGG    logFC  4.268764
6    hsa-miR-497-3p_CAAACCACACTGTGGTGTTGGA 1.5307936 60.67202 6.742159e-15 2.449539e-11  hsa-miR-497-3p    CAAACCACACTGTGGTGTTGGA    logFC -3.126917
```

output:

```
mir             up  down
hsa-miR-21-5p   1   0
hsa-miR-135b-5p 4   0
hsa-miR-497-3p  0   1
```

Comment: Try `table(transform(df1[c('X1', 'value')], value=value>0))`

Comment: perfect. plese post it as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `table` after subsetting the dataset

```
 table(transform(df1[c('X1', 'value')], value=value>0))
```