# Count number of unique levels of a variable

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to get a simple way to count the number of distinct categories in a column of a dataframe.

For example, in the iris data frame, there are 150 rows with one of the columns being species, of which there are 3 different species.  I want to be able to run this bit of code and determine that there are 3 different species in that column.  I do not care how many rows each of those unique entries correspond to, just how many distinct variables there are, which is mostly what I found in my research.

I was thinking something like this:

```
df <- iris
choices <- count(unique(iris$Species))
```

Does a solution as simple as this exist?  I have looked at these posts, but they either examine the entire data frame rather than a single column in that data frame or provide a more complicated solution than what I am hoping for.

[count number of instances in data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31501626/count-number-of-instances-in-data-frame)

[Count number of occurrences of categorical variables in data frame (R)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36700028/count-number-of-occurrences-of-categorical-variables-in-data-frame-r)

[How to count number of unique character vectors within a subset of data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38461540/how-to-count-number-of-unique-character-vectors-within-a-subset-of-data)

Comment: Try `choices <- length(unique(iris$Species))`

Comment: @ImranAli that was perfect as long as I specified `choices <- as.numeric(length(unique(iris$Species)))`

If you make your comment an answer I will mark it as correct.

Comment: I have added my comment as answer

Comment: To get count for all columns: `lengths(lapply(iris, unique))` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22196078/r-count-unique-values-for-every-column

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The following should do the job:

```
choices <- length(unique(iris$Species))
```

Answer (score 4):

If we are using `dplyr`, `n_distinct` would get the number of unique elements in each column

```
library(dplyr)
iris %>%
      summarise_each(funs(n_distinct))
#  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
#1           35          23           43          22       3
```

Answer (score 3):

If your need is to count the number of unique instances for each column of your data.frame, you can use `sapply`:

```
sapply(iris, function(x) length(unique(x)))
#### Sepal.Length  Sepal.Width Petal.Length  Petal.Width      Species 
####  35           23          43            22               3
```

For just one specific colum, the code suggested by @Imran Ali (in the comments) is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 3):

Using data.table is easier:

```
require(data.table)
uniqueN(iris$Species)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to count unique values across all columns in 'iris' :

```
> df <- iris

> df$Species <- as.character(df$Species)

> aggregate(values ~ ind, unique(stack(df)), length)
           ind values
1 Petal.Length     43
2  Petal.Width     22
3 Sepal.Length     35
4  Sepal.Width     23
5      Species      3
>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another simple way to count with Tidyverse package:

```
iris %>% 
  count(Species)

     Species  n
1     setosa 50
2 versicolor 50
3  virginica 50
```

Comment: They asked about counting the number of unique values, not how to count the number of observations in each group

Answer (score 0):

[Dplyr version 1](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/across.html) introduced [across](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/across.html), which makes this task relatively straightforward along with `n_distinct()`:

```r
library(dplyr)

# for a specific column
iris %>% 
  summarise(across(Species, n_distinct))
#   Species
# 1       3

# only for factors
iris %>% 
  summarise(across(where(is.factor), nlevels))
#   Species
# 1       3

# for all columns 
iris %>% 
  summarise(across(everything(), n_distinct))
#   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
# 1           35          23           43          22       3
```